# OpenGL is averaging all colors in the texture?

Tags: opengl, colors, shader

I setup my texture parameters in opengl like this:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);`

//glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
```

My data for the texture is this:

```
checker[0] = checker[1] = checker[2] = 255;
checker[3] = checker[4] = checker[5] = 0;
checker[6] = checker[7] = checker[8] = 255;
checker[9] = checker[10] = checker[11] = 0;
```

My texture is in GL_RGB and takes GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE. I set the width and height of the texture to 2 and my coordinates to place the texture is composed of two triangles that make a square and fill up the whole screen.

However I get a grey color instead of two black and two white pixels. The grey color is exatly 128,127,127 in RGB. I read that I should add one byte of padding to checker for every color, but that gave me a peach color.

EDIT:

I found a bug but now I get a white screen.

So I removed

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

and now I get a black screen.

This is my draw function:

```
glUseProgram(gfx->shaderProgramTexture);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0,
    2, 2, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    gfx->vertexBufferTexture);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
gfx->clearScreen();
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glfwSwapBuffers(gfx->getWindow());
```

Comment: Are you sure the texture is bound when you set the parameters? We need more code in order to debug this.

Comment: What have you set `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to?

Comment: For one you should keep the min/mag fliters to `GL_NEAREST` but also can you show us your texture coords and shader?

Comment: Also what are you doing to make this a "full screen quad" and not a incredibly large quad?

Comment: Are you calling `glTexImage2D()` somewhere? You can't just call `glTexSubImage2D()` without calling `glTexImage2D()` first. And as @genpfault already hinted, set the unpack alignment to 1.

Answer (score -1):

You don't mention where your texture coordinates come from. Using the wrong texture coordinates might result in rendering something entirely white or entirely black, for example if you always sample the same pixel. You might get grey without the GL_NEAREST if your texture coordinates are exactly in between the pixels.

Comment: No, you will not get any mix between the texels when using the `GL_NEAREST` filter, no matter what texture coordinates you use.

Comment: That is why I said "You might get grey without the GL_NEAREST", note the word "without".